bash read -ra command drops end of array when transferring from long string
I have a bash script that uses "read -ra" to convert a long delimited string into an array.  At small string lengths the script works fine, but for a longer string (6561 words, 135726 characters) the end of the string is not converted into array elements.
I'm trying to convert data in an ExodusII-format ascii file to xyz format for plotting with gnuplot, using a script run from the command line.  The input (ExodusII txt) file has the format
coordx = 1, 1.0125, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1, 1.00625, 1.025,
    1.025, 1.01875, 1.025, 1.01875, 1.01875, 1.0375, 1.0375, 1.03125, 1.0375,
[snip]
    1.46875, 1.4875, 1.4875, 1.48125, 1.48125, 1.5, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.49375 ;

 coordy = 1, 1, 1.0125, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1.00625, 1,
    1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125,
[snip]
    1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375 ;

 vals_nod_var1 =
  1.50711777303835e-07, 4.54731383295358e-07, 1.4039653539437e-06,
    4.54743954548528e-07, 3.02721580299597e-07, 9.29348368619529e-07,
[snip]
    -1.08946977710559e-10, -1.40259016278983e-10 ;

My plan is to use a bash script to read each list into a separate array (coordx[$i], coordy[$i], values[$i]) so I can print to a file in the format
  coordx[1]   coordy[1]   vals[1]
  coordx[2]   coordy[2]   vals[2]

...
The section of the bash script that's giving me trouble is this:
str_vals=$(sed -n "$startline_v,$endline_v p" "$file" | xargs)
IFS=', ' read -ra vals <<< "$str_vals"
str_coordx=$(sed -n "$startline_x,$endline_x p" "$file" | xargs)
IFS=', ' read -ra coordx <<< "$str_coordx"
str_coordy=$(sed -n "$startline_y,$endline_y p" "$file" | xargs)
IFS=', ' read -ra coordy <<< "$str_coordy"


This correctly reads each list of numbers into a single string delimited by ", ".  If I echo that string it's always been the correct length (in that "wc -w [string]" gives the correct number of words).  (The sed commands above read in a few garbage elements like "coordx","=",";" which are thrown away when printing.)
This script works correctly with an input file of 441 array elements.
But moving to a larger data set with 6561 elements, arrays $coordx and $coordy are processed correctly, but ${#vals[@]} is only 6355.  If I print the $vals array, the value of val[6354] is correct and all the elements val[6355] and beyond are empty.
I cannot find any special characters at that data point in the input file that might terminate the read command.  All I can see that's different between $coordx and $vals is that $vals has more characters.  Checking if I could be exceeding a character limit for the read command I find that when reading a long string into a variable I'm not limited by ARG_MAX, so that shouldn't be a problem, right?  (In any case, ARG_MAX on this machine is 6291456 and the number of characters in $str_vals is 135726)
This is on a machine running Kubuntu 22.04.  Any tips appreciated.  Thanks!

IFS is not a multi-character delimiter. IFS=", " uses either a comma or a space as field separators, not the single string ', '. That could be related.

Frankly, I would not use shell to handle such large arrays in any case. Use just about any other language instead.

Thanks @chepner.  I saw that IFS will treat any non-whitespace character as the delimiter, so I figured the extra space might not be relevant (since in this application it doesn't matter if my array elements include any trailing whitespace).  But you're right.  I added a pipe to tr -d ' ' to remove the whitespace and leave only the comma delimiter.  Same behavior.
And yeah, I was wondering if bash is just the wrong tool.  I thought it was a simple enough task to be shell-script-worthy, but didn't anticipate an issue with data size.  I appreciate your taking a look.

In general, shell scripts are for running other programs, not operating on data directly.

Point taken.  I need more practice in Python anyway.  Thanks again.

Setting a variable by itself isn't affected by ARG_MAX, but sed ... | xargs is, and depending on your system xargs may use lower limit(s). I would try str=$(sed ... | tr -d ' \n;') to remove everything but data and commas then split; if your file does or may use CRLF for linebreaks, which we can't see in the post, also delete \r

Beautiful!  Thanks -- yes, the \n in the tr command did the trick.  Script works now.  Much appreciated.

See How to concatenate multiple lines of output to one line? for more reliable alternatives to xargs for combining multiple lines into one.

Sorry -- forgot to cite @dave_thompson_085 in my comment for offering the solution.  But I also understand bash probably the wrong way to approach this.  Thanks all.

as mentioned - bash is less than ideal for this, here's a (gnu) awk script that might suit. based on your posted samples, this generates python lists that can then be imported into your python app ...
$0 ~ /=/ { # initialisation (cater for multiple entries)
    arr=$1
    offset=index($0, "=")
    if ( records[arr] )
        records[arr] = (records[arr] "" ) substr( $0, offset+1)
    else
        records[arr] = substr( $0, offset+1)
    next
}
{
    records[arr] = (records[arr] "" $0)
}

END{
    for ( rec in records ){
        gsub(/;/,",",records[rec] )
        print rec "= [" records[rec] "]" #pythonic list
    }
}

$ gawk -f parse.awk l > coords.py

$ python
Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 10:14:12) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from coords import coordx, coordy, vals_nod_var1
>>> coordx
[1, 1.0125, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1, 1.00625, 1.025, 1.025, 1.01875, 1.025, 1.01875, 1.01875, 1.0375, 1.0375, 1.03125, 1.0375, 1.46875, 1.4875, 1.4875, 1.48125, 1.48125, 1.5, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.49375]
>>> 
>>> coordy
[1, 1, 1.0125, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1.00625, 1, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.00625, 1, 1.0125, 1, 1.00625, 1.0125, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375, 1.5, 1.49375]
>>> 
>>> vals_nod_var1
[1.50711777303835e-07, 4.54731383295358e-07, 1.4039653539437e-06, 4.54743954548528e-07, 3.02721580299597e-07, 9.29348368619529e-07, -1.08946977710559e-10, -1.40259016278983e-10]
>>> 

feel free to use/update/ignore as you see fit.

Thank you @ticktalk!  I will add the steps for finding the right file locations to extract the data.  This is a great help.  (Not enough reputation to upvote, but wanted to acknowledge.)
